# Grid store config throws "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'buffered' of undefined"

Tags: search, extjs, grid, store, extjs4.1

I have form and grid. the user must enter data in form fields then display related records in the grid.

I want to implement a search form, e.g: user will type the name and gender of the student,
then will get a grid of all students have the same name and gender.

So, I use Ajax to send form fields value to PHP and then create a `json_encode` which will be used in grid store.

I am really not sure if my idea is good. But I haven't found another way to do that.

The problem is there is a mistake in my store but I couldn't figure out what it is. I get this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'buffered' of undefined`

**My View:**

```
{
  xtype: 'panel',
  layout: "fit",
  id: 'searchResult',
  flex: 7,
  title: '<div style="text-align:center;"/>SearchResultGrid</div>',
  items: [{
    xtype: 'gridpanel',
    store: 'advSearchStore',
    id: 'AdvSearch-grid',
    columns: [{
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        align: 'right',
        text: 'name'
      }, {
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        dataIndex: 'gender',
        align: 'right',
        text: 'gender'
      }
    ],
    viewConfig: {
      id: 'Arr',
      emptyText: 'noResult'
    },
    requires: ['MyApp.PrintSave_toolbar'],
    dockedItems: [{
      xtype: 'PrintSave_tb',
      dock: 'bottom',
    }]
  }]
}
```

**My Controller:**

```
.
.
.
xmlhttp.open("GET","AdvSearch.php?search_name="+search_name,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

**My PHP script:**

```
if (!$con) {
    throw new Exception("Error in connection to DB");
}

$query ="SELECT name, gender FROM students  WHERE name ILIKE '%$search_name%' ";
$result = pg_query($query); 

while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
   $Arr[] = array('name' => $row[0], 'gender' => $row[1]);
}

$searchResult_list = array();
$searchResult_list['success'] = true;
$searchResult_list['Arr'] = $Arr;

$searchResult_list['totalCount'] = count( $searchResult_list['Arr'] );

echo json_encode($searchResult_list); 

if (!$result) 
    die("Error in query: " . pg_last_error());

pg_close($con);
```

**My Store, Model:**

```
Ext.define('AdvSearchPost', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'AdvSearch.php',
    reader: {
      type: 'json',
      root: 'Arr',
      totalProperty: 'totalCount'
    }
  },
  fields: [{
      name: 'name'
    }, {
      name: 'type_and_cargo'
    }
  ]
});
advSearchStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
  pageSize: 10,
  model: 'AdvSearchPost'
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well it is just a typo of your storename.

The error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'buffered' of undefined`only indicates that the store could not be bound. It may be a bit misleading.

Try the grid with either

```
store: advSearchPost
```

or

```
store: Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('AdvSearchPost') // if in any form a controller takes care about your store
```

and it will work.

**Edit**

I guess you haven't any controller so I recommend you to create your store like this

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
   pageSize: 10,
   model: 'AdvSearchPost',
   storeId: 'AdvSearchPost'
});
```

That will enable you to receive the store by the `StoreManager` from everywhere (after it is created). That will also enable the last statement to work without any controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot! the error is gone but still the result not shown in the grid even it returned successfully in the firebug. What do you suggest?

Comment: @Oxi You're welcome :) Well this is hard to tell without the JSON respond from your server. But I guess it depends on the returned JSON and the reader configuration. You have to check if your JSON is valied and your reader is properly configured (total property, root property, id property, and so on)

Comment: thanks buddy, I came across the same issue and resolved by you suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you call like this.. 
`store: Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('bla bla bla')` won't throw any error in the console.

Replace **store** parameter with **storeId** and then assign your actual store to it which will connect to your actual store. `storeId:advSearchPost`